# How to see the validation error after each epoch in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am using keras to train a model for regression. My code looks like:

```
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=2)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,
                                                    train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25)
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

> The problem is that it is dramatically overfitting. How can I see the
>   validation error after each epoch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transmit [parameters](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) to KerasRegressor fit method:

> validation_split: float (0. < x < 1). Fraction of the data to use as
>   held-out validation data. validation_data: tuple (x_val, y_val) or
>   tuple (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights) to be used as held-out
>   validation data. Will override validation_split.

via Pipeline [fit method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit):

> **fit_params : dict of string -> object Parameters passed to the fit method of each step, where each parameter name is prefixed such that
>   parameter p for step s has key s__p.

Example:

```
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train, mlp__validation_split=0.3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will ask a different question about the overfitting problem.